# Running awesome-client (which uses dbus) from acpid

Tags: systemd, acpi, awesome-wm, dbus

I set up a acpid rule to execute the following command, whenever I receive a specific acpi message:

```
awesome-client "activate_tabletmode()"
```

Where `activate_tabletmode()` is just some function that I want to call in my awesome config. I know that `awesome-client` uses dbus to make IPC with awesome possible.

I get the following error message:

```
Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: Using X11 for dbus-daemon
autolaunch was disabled at compile time, set your DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS instead
```

Can someone help me understand what that means? I tried to run the command as user instead of root using `sudo -u`, but it did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that services and user sessions run in completely separate environments, so a service does not automatically know how to reach into your desktop session. Each user gets their own X11 display address, and the same goes for D-Bus – AwesomeWM is running on a "session bus" that's separate for each user and not associated with the global "system bus".

(There can be *more than one* user session at the same time, so it wouldn't really make sense to have fixed paths and addresses.)

> I tried to run the command as user instead of root using sudo -u, but it did not help.

That's a good start – running the command as the same UID is mandatory for being able to access a session bus. However, you still need to tell it *where* the session bus is.

Fortunately, in recent systems, the session bus path is no longer chosen randomly, but based only on your UID. So if your user ID is `uid=$(id -u fred)`, you need to set at least one of the following environment variables:

1. `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/$uid"`
2. `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/$uid/bus"`

For example:

```
sudo -u fred XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/$(id -u fred)" awesome-client "activate_tabletmode()"
```

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer :) It worked after setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR.